# output text and a matrix in the plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following problem:

I need to create a picture which consists of a plot, histogram, specific text and example of a matrix. I found a way how to do part of the task:

```
    png('Erdos-Renyi.png', width=800, height=800)
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    plot(g, main=paste('Erdos-Renyi model, V=', V, ' E=',E, sep=""))
    hist(degree(g))
    ...
    dev.off()
```

In two additional plots I would like to output a text and a matrix. I tried to achieve this with `text` and `mtext` commands, but with no success.

[image]

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Although there are some packages (as mentioned below) that can help, R is not very well set up for formatting information outside of plots. I would recommend using Sweave if you're familiar with latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `addtable2plot` function in `plotrix`

```
m<-round(matrix(runif(36),ncol=3,nrow=3),2)
plot(1:10)
addtable2plot (x=2,y=7,table=m)
```

[image]